# Obtener días entre dos fechas basadas en 1 año de 360 días JAVA

Tags: java, mysql

Alguno sabe la forma de calcular los días contables entre dos fechas. En contabilidad se asume que cada mes tiene 30 días, entonces un año tiene 360 días.

Lo he estado haciendo en Java, pero me trae la cantidad de días corrientes.

Esto lo necesito para calcular la liquidación de un empleado, cesantías, intereses a las Cesantias, vacaciones y prima.

Las fechas las traigo de una tabla de MySQL.

He aquí el código que he construido.:

El método `getEmp_fingrs()` me trae la fecha de ingreso del empleado.
El método `getEmp_frtr()` me trae la fecha de retiro del empleado.

```
private void liquidar(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    String cedula=request.getParameter("numdoc");
    
    Empleado empleado=modelEmpleado.getEmpleado(cedula);

    double censantias=calculaCesantias(empleado.getEmp_sueldo(),empleado.getEmp_fingrs(),empleado.getEmp_frtr());
    double interesesCesantias=calculaInteresesCesantias(censantias,empleado.getEmp_fingrs(),empleado.getEmp_frtr());
    double vacaciones=calculaVacaciones(empleado.getEmp_sueldo(),empleado.getEmp_fingrs(),empleado.getEmp_frtr());
    double prima=calculaPrima(empleado.getEmp_sueldo(),empleado.getEmp_fingrs(),empleado.getEmp_frtr());
}

private double calculaPrima(double emp_sueldo, Date emp_fingrs, Date emp_frtr) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

private double calculaVacaciones(double emp_sueldo, Date emp_fingrs, Date emp_frtr) {
    
    return emp_sueldo*CalcularDiasLaborados(emp_fingrs,emp_frtr)/720;
}

private double calculaInteresesCesantias(double censantias, Date emp_fingrs, Date emp_frtr) {
    
    return censantias*CalcularDiasLaborados(emp_fingrs,emp_frtr)*0.12/360;
}

public int CalcularDiasLaborados(Date emp_fingrs, Date emp_frtr){
    
    //Cálculo de Días Trabajados
            long diff=emp_frtr.getTime()-emp_fingrs.getTime();
            long diffDays = diff/(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)+1; 
            int daysdiff = (int) diffDays; 
    
    return daysdiff;
}

private double calculaCesantias(double emp_sueldo, Date emp_fingrs, Date emp_frtr) {
    
    return emp_sueldo*CalcularDiasLaborados(emp_fingrs,emp_frtr)/360;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y probaste escribir una funcion que calcule las fechas como vos queres que se calculen?

Comment: Puedes agregar a la pregunta un ejemplo del resultado esperado?

Comment: El intervalo entre las dos fechas serian ambas del mismo anno y meses distintos?

Comment: Coges las fechas, miras cuantos años hay entre ellas, multiplicas cada año por 12, miras cuántos meses hay, sumas al anterior valor y multiplicas todo por 30, para finalizar, sumas la cantidad de dias de diferencia entre ambas fechas... ya tienes el total de días!

Comment: Hola, las fechas serían del mismo año. Ejemplo: Fecha Inicio= 1/01/2020 y Fecha Retiro= 13/11/2020; en días contables serían 313 días pero en Java me salen los días corrientes, osea 317 días. Muchas gracias.

Comment: y de meses diferentes?

Comment: @Alejandro Simplemente digo que en vez de usar los objetos de java para manejar las fechas, hagas las operaciones tú! Si java no tiene años de 360 días, crea una fecha que si lo tenga, y usa tus clases con tu lógica para trabajar. La operación para calcular cuantos días van de una fecha `X` a una fecha `Y` no son difíciles, restar, sumar, multiplicar y dividir. Y si lo haces tú a mano, tus meses pueden tener los días que quieras. De hecho es mucho más fácil si todos tus meses tienen 30 días que si no :)

Comment: @Benito-B Si es posible regalame un ejemplo por favor, creo que aún no he comprendido. El ejemplo puede ser entre las fechas: Fecha Inicio= 1/01/2020 y Fecha Retiro= 13/11/2020

Comment: @Alejandro, las fechas son de meses diferentes?

Comment: @Japv hola, podriamos hacer el ejemplo con estas fechas Fecha Inicio= 1/enero/2020 y Fecha Retiro= 13/noviembre/2020

Comment: Dime que versión usas de Java

Comment: @Japv Hola, uso Versión 8 de Java

Comment: perfecto dame un tiempo

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias :)

Comment: necesito que me digas para probar el algoritmo cual es la diferencia que hay en dias contables entre las fechas 13/01/2021 y 01/03/2021. Dime ademas la diferencia que hay en dias contables entre las fechas 13/01/2021 y 01/02/2021

Comment: Hola @Japv los días contables asumen que todos los meses son de 30 días, por ende se asume un año de 360 días (12 meses por 30 días) , en este caso los días contables entre las fechas 13/01/2021 y 01/03/2021 serían 48 días (17 dias de enero, 30 días de febrero y 1 día de marzo), mientras que contando los días comun y corriente serían 47 días (18 días de enero, 28 días de febrero y 1 día de marzo).  Para el ejemplo de las fechas 13/01/2021 y 01/02/2021 en días contables serían 18 días, mientras que comun y corriente serían 19 días.

Answer (score 0):

Comparto avance del código. ejemplo de fechas 01/01/2020 al 13/11/2020.

Creo que está cumpliendo con lo cometido.
Lo dejo por acá por si alguien piensa que se puede mejorar.
El código también cuenta los días de años diferentes.

```
package Dias360;


public class ContarDias {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            int diaInicio=13;
            int mesInicio=05;
            int anoInicio=2013;
            
            int diaFin=26;
            int mesFin=8;
            int anoFin=2020;
            
            int contDias=0;
            
        for(int h=anoInicio; h<=anoFin; h++){
            
            if(anoInicio<anoFin){
                mesFin=12;
            }
            
            if(h==anoFin){
                mesFin=8; //Este valor debe ser igual al mesFin inicial
            }
                
            for(int i=mesInicio;i<=mesFin;i++){
                for(int j=diaInicio;j<=30;j++){
                    
                    if(i==mesFin && j==diaFin && h==anoFin){
                        break;
                    }
                    
                    contDias++;
                    
                }
                diaInicio=1;
                
            }
            mesInicio=1;
        }
            
            System.out.println("Dias Contables"+(contDias+1));
            
        }
    
}
```

Comment: Creo que estás buscando una solución mucho más complicada de lo que necesitas, usando un montón de loops para *contar* días, cuando puedes multiplicar directamente... `int contDias = (mesFin - mesInicio) * 30 + diaFin - diaInicio;` debería dar el mismo resultado, sin iterar cientos de veces. Edito: Lo he comprobado, la operación que te indico da exactamente el mismo resultado que el loop... tal como te dije en un comentario hace unos días :)

Comment: Hola @Benito-B Muchas gracias por tu solución. Entonces para años diferentes la solución podría ser:     int Dias= (((anoFin-anoInicio) *12) + (mesFin - mesInicio)) * 30 + diaFin - diaInicio;

Comment: Es un buen comienzo, pero tendrás que tener cuidado porque no sé si funcionará bien en caso de que sean años diferentes, pero haya menos de 12 meses entre ellos, por ejemplo: `01-12-2011` y `01-03-2012`, son diferentes años, pero en realidad han pasado tres meses nada más! Tendrás que empezar a añadir alguna comprobación :)